# How to use xpath in python to list attribute values

Tags: python, xpath

I'm using the below python code to do an xpath attribute lookup, but getting an error:
**selector.append(ops[token[0]](next, token))
KeyError: '@'**
Just using the starndard python2.7 release with no extra modules

The xml file looks like:

```
<rule-set>
<rule name="firstRule" salience="3" />
<rule name="secondRule" salience="5" />
</rule-set>
```

The my code looks like:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
fp = open("./rules.xml", "r")
elementTree = ET.parse(fp)
e = elementTree.findall('rule') #looking up element, this works
for i in e:
    print i.attrib
e = elementTree.findall('rule/@salience') #directly looking up attribute fails
for i in e:
    print i
print 'all done'
```

I'm a bit confused, ... I thought this xpath lookup would be supported with xpath1.0, or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support)

> This module provides limited support for XPath expressions for locating elements in a tree. The goal is to support a small subset of the abbreviated syntax; a full XPath engine is outside the scope of the module.

The `xml.etree` module doesn't allow to select attributes directly using it's [xpath syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax), only to select elements having certain attributes.

If you want a more complete xpath support, you should look into [`lxml`](http://lxml.de).[`etree`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)